# MYSQL Fetch Date and Time Stored as String and ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, datetime, sql-order-by

I have a specific reason for storing Date and Time in DataBase Table as String in below format

> DateFmt = "dd-MM-yyyy";
>   TimeFmt = "hh:mm a";

Now while fetching I want to sort by converting the string to Date and Time and sort to display in TableView, so the row with newer ones come on top.

This wil work if we store as date and time,

```
ORDER BY `DATE` DESC, `TIME` DESC
```

How do we convert from String and use order by

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `str_to_date()`:

```
order by str_to_date(date, '%d-%m-%Y')
```

I should add:  I can think of no good reason for storing a date in that format in the database.  You should be using the built-in date/time types.  They exist for a reason.

If you do have to store a date as a string (which I have to do occasionally), you should use YYYY-MM-DD format.  This is ISO standard, converts readily to a date, and sorts correctly.

Comment: I am using Indian format dd-MM-yyyy. So I am storing it as string.

Comment: @SujayUN . . . You can convert it to a string when you *output* it, using `date_format()`.  There is no reason to store it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

I came with the solution like this :

SQL :

```
SELECT * FROM NamTbl
    ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(DateCol,' ',TimeCol), '%d-%m-%Y %h:%i') DESC
```

SQLite :

```
"SELECT * FROM " + NamTblVar +
             " ORDER BY STRFTIME('%d-%m-%Y %h:%i'," + DateKolVar + "|| ' ' ||" + TimeKolVar + ") DESC;";
```

Comment: I should thank @Gordon Linoff for the hint and helping to get this solution